# .NET 4.6 Re-installation on Windows 10

Tags: installation, windows-10, .net-framework, windows-10-upgrade

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. Then I uninstalled .NET Framework 4.6 in Windows 10. It's not appearing in Programs and Features anymore.

I want to reinstall it, and I tried to use the installer from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48130. But the installation fails with message `The .NET Framework 4.6 redistributable does not apply to this operating system. Please download the .NET Framework 4.6 for your operating system from the Microsoft Download Center`.

Here is the installation log:

> OS Version = 10.0.10240, SP = 0.0, Platform 2
>
> OS Description = Future OS - x64 Unkonw Edition (ProductType=101)
>
> MSI = 5.0.10240.16386
>
> Windows servicing = 10.0.10240.16464
>
> CommandLine = C:\e2e99de5e6e04fcfe49702\Setup.exe /x86 /x64 /web
>
> Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
>
> Operation: Installing
>
> Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Setup
>
> Package Version = 4.6.00081
>
> User Experience Data Collection Policy: AlwaysUploaded
>
> Logging all the global blocks
>
> Installation Blockers:
>
> The .NET Framework 4.6 redistributable does not apply to this operating system. Please download the .NET Framework 4.6 for your operating system from the Microsoft Download Center.
>
> Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x000013EC), "A StopBlock was hit or a System Requirement was not met." (Elapsed time: 0 00:00:04).

How can I reinstall .NET 4.6?

Comment: How did you uninstall it exactly?    Have you tried enabling it in Win10's "Turn Windows features on or off"?

Comment: Windows 10 already includes .Net Framework 4.6, so you can't uninstalled/re-install it. Explain your real issue that you try to solve.

Answer (score 5):

Open PowerShell as administrator and run:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName NetFx4
```

.NET Framework 4.6 is part of the OS and can not/should not be installed from an external package.

**Edit:**

If you actually removed .NET from the system, PowerShell will not work, open a command prompt `cmd.exe` as administrator and run:

```
dism.exe -Enable-Feature -online -FeatureName:NetFx4
```

Comment: But what if I get 0x800f0813 error after I run this command? I run both variants.

Comment: @Suncatcher i have the same problem! Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No, I haven't fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade to Win 10 "disabled" Dot Net. I've seen this happen to my clients. Since Dot Net is included in the Win 10 OS, it does not show up as an installed application in "Programs and Features" but you CAN find it under Features.

There are like two or three places where you may want to re-enable Dot Net (depending upon how you or your applications are using it). For me, under the heading ".NET Framework 4.6 Advanced Services" I had to check "HTTP Activation". But you may also need to look under "Windows Process Activation Service" as well as "Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services\Application Development Features".

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try installing it from [windows 10 sdk](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) that include .Net 4.6 Framework